# Invalid kubernetes YAML spec , failed to load spec for resource harness

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3, tap-harness, maven-plugin-testing-harness

I have harness and kubernetes hooked up and i am able to deploy nginx chart using helm succesfully.

Now i have another helm chart that I want to deploy but when i do so in harness, it fails during the helm deployment phase

> “Invalid kubernetes YAML Spec. Failed to load spec for resource kind :
> Deployment, name . Cannot create property=spec for
> javabean=class v1Deployment in ‘reader’, line 10, column 3.

I can deploy the helm chart manually with no issues, but when i try to do it in harness i get the above.

Any ideas on how to identify what the error may be?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have selected kubernetes manifests as the source but actually it is a helm chart.
Change the remote manifest format from kubernetes resources specs to Helm Chart from Source Repository.